# Why I don't use my drag and drop script in my bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I have three files in my directory (in path only ANCII symbols) ...

1. Dump my database in db.sql format (-rw-rw-r--)
2. db.desktop file (-rw-rw-r--)
3. restoredb.sh script (-rw-rw-r--)

```
$ cat db.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Drop Over Me
Comment=Execute the script with the file dropped
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "/home/sergei/migrations/restoredb.sh \"%u\""
Icon=utilities-terminal
Type=Application

$ cat restoredb.sh

#!/usr/bin/bash

docker exec -i mysql5 sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -pr00t -e "drop database my_db; create database ipdb character set UTF8 collate utf8_general_ci;"'
docker exec -i mysql5 sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -pr00t my_db' < $1

sleep 500
```

... but I want run bash script via desktop file I get next error

> /home/sergei/migrations/restoredb.sh: line 4:
> '/home/sergei/migrations/db.sql'

Why I get this error? Thank you!

Comment: `/home/sergei/migrations/restoredb.sh: line 4` are you sure you are inspect proper file? `Why I get this error?` Is this the _full_ error message? Does your file has dos line endings?

Comment: This file from Mac OS, but see LF in editor.

Comment: I just tried your `db.desktop` file on Ubuntu 18.04, and it worked fine. But I had to change `restoredb.sh`'s permissions to include `u+x`. Does it work for you to run (from the terminal): `gnome-terminal -e "/home/sergei/migrations/restoredb.sh /home/sergei/migrations/db.sql"`?

Comment: Hmm, it is not work. The same error.

Comment: I expect what I may success running $ /home/sergei/migrations/restoredb.sh /home/sergei/migrations/db.sql, but have fail. Path is correct (use ls for test).